# Why do a "Lazy Binary Search"?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, lazy-evaluation

Someone asked about Lazy Binary Searches today. Not knowing what that was, I looked for it, and found this post: [What is Lazy Binary Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958786/what-is-lazy-binary-search) Essentially, a Lazy Binary Search is a Binary Search where you compare for inequalities first, and only compare for equality once - at the end.

What's the point? Under what circumstances is checking if `A<B` easy to do, but checking if `A=B` is so hard you want to avoid it if possible?

Comment: It's one less comparison per iteration.

Comment: At the cost of more iterations.

Comment: Indeed.  But sometimes all you care about is worst-case performance (consider hard real-time applications, or a pipelined hardware implementation).

Comment: Why would the number of iterations be greater?

Comment: The number of iterations is almost constant - log2 of the series size (rounded up or down, probably depending on chance)

Comment: I think lcc's reason is enough for its name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one less comparison per iteration.

Of course, that's at the expense of a worse average runtime (you don't get the opportunity to return early).<sup>1</sup>  But sometimes all you care about is worst-case runtime (consider hard-real-time applications, or a pipelined hardware implementation).

---

<sub>1. Although the asymptotic complexity doesn't change.</sub>

Comment: I still stay 'lazy' is a bad name for it. It should be called ConsistentBinarySearch or something. Ah well, at least it makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One thing the lazy search does is find the *first* element in the sequence that's equal to the target (assuming the target is in the sequence).

If you have several elements that match the target, a non-lazy search would get you any one of those.

So, the C++ library's `binary_search` could be implemented as non-lazy (and I imagine it usually is), while `lower_bound` cannot.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice side-effect, but it's probably not what they thought about when they named it 'Lazy' and not 'LowestAnswerBinarySearch'.

Comment: Well, the question is "why use it", not "why is it called Lazy".  Even so, these things aren't always named by a property of the result, but sometimes by a property of how it works. "lazy" is catchier to boot.

Comment: Also, it seems that "lazy binary search" isn't a very widely used term.  The only places I see it used, based on a not very thorough Google search, is asking what it is (here on SO) and on the lectures & assignments for a particular class at Rutgers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its just that in the "LAZY" search, you skip checking for equality every time you compare the element X to the center element. It is only at the very end that you check for equality. I guess all you are doing is reducing the search by one `==` condition.

Comment: But you are increasing the number of iterations. Maybe 'Lazy' is just a bad name for it?

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you saying the number of iterations would increase?

Comment: Because you always iterate to the end - log2(length of series) times. You never stop before that, even if the item you're looking for is found on the first iteration.

Comment: I don't get it. If I compare the middle element in the first iteration with X and if `<` and `>` is false wouldn't I `break` the loop? (I might be wrong)

Comment: You just check if A<B and modify your pointers according to that. See the pseudo-code in the link I provided.